# Does C# regex support embedding regex options directly inside the regex itself?

Tags: c#, regex, syntax

Some regular expression engines support embedding regex options directly inside the regex itself. Like `(?i)is`, which matches the string `is` ignoring cases. Does C# support this feature? I skimmed over the documentation at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex__ctor_System_String_), but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class MainClass {
  public static void Main (string[] args) {
    string text = "is, IS";
    string regex = "(?i)is";
    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, regex);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}", matches.Count, text);
  }
}
```

Output:

```
2 matches found in:
   is, IS
```

Comment: A counter example would prove that the option was effective (as opposed to by default).